# Laravel <title> in <body>

Tags: html, laravel, http-headers, title, document-body

I mixed two examples from Laravel [tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data),and receive result, which I hope you help me to understand.
My route file is :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('child', ['name' => 'Samantha']);
```

child.blade.php is

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection
Hello, {{ $name }}.
@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

And master.blade.php is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output is

```
Hello, Samantha. This is the master sidebar. This is appended to the master sidebar. This is my body content.
```

Page source code is

```
Hello, Samantha.

<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

                        This is the master sidebar.


    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>

        <div class="container">
                <p>This is my body content.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inspecting tool shows me empty `<head>` and `<title>` in `<body>` .

Why this happens with `Hello, {{ $name }}` and why inspecting tool lie to me about page body?

And、 if I put in @section `Hello, {{ $name }}` all will look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your child template extends layout, all data you have in it must be enclosed into a section

`Hello, {{ $name }}.` isn't in a section so it will be print at top of your output.

You can see extending template like a buffer. It starts taking contain of your child because it's the file you provide in your controller, then wrap it's content in sections defined in the layout.